# Memory reference issue for function return (React Javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, memory, return

So I am working in React.js. I need to generate three versions of the same list, but with a different set of markets contained inside of each of the three events.
I expect the events to be the same. But when they are linked to the markets, each of the three same events might have a different sub-set of markets based on the filer.

```
organiseEvents(timeFilter) {
    const propevents = this.props.Properties.events;
    const propmarkets = this.props.Properties.markets;
    const propselections = this.props.Properties.selections;

    let events = new Array();

    propevents.forEach(e => {
        e.Markets = propmarkets.filter(m => m.Values.eventid === e.Id && m.Values.name.toUpperCase().includes(timeFilter));
        e.Markets.forEach(m => {
            m.Selections = propselections.filter(s => s.Values.marketid === m.Id);
        });

        events.push(e);
    });

    if(events.length > 0) {
    events = events.sort(function (a, b) { return a.Values.homerotation - b.Values.homerotation });
    return events;
    } else{
    return [];
    }
}

render() {
    let events = this.organiseEvents("");
    let midevents = this.organiseEvents("MIDEVENT");
    let postevents = this.organiseEvents("POSTEVENT");
}
```

The issue I am having is:

- this.organiseEvents("") runs: events contains two 'event' objects with three markets each.
- this.organiseEvents("MIDEVENT") runs: midevents contains the same two 'event' objects, but with no markets as there was no market to match the filter.
- events also becomes the result of this.organiseEvents("MIDEVENT").
- events and midevents will then become the result of this.organiseEvents("POSTEVENT")

There is a reference issue somewhere and I can't for the life of me spot it. I feel like I am missing the obvious.

Each three let variables should be three completely separate representations of the same two events, but with varying markets contained within.

One fix I have discovered in the mean time is the following:

```
    let events = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.organiseEvents("")));
    let midevents = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.organiseEvents("MIDEVENT")));
    let postevents = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.organiseEvents("POSTEVENT")));
```

This forces each of the three values to not reference the same place. However, it is a dirty fix in my eyes that conveniently fixes the problem rather than me understanding what the problem is and fixing it properly.

Thanks.

Comment: your issue is due to reference problem  in  3 lines `const propevents = this.props.Properties.events;` and `e.Markets =  propmarkets.filter....;`. and  `m.Selections =  propselections.filter....`  As every  time you call `this.organizeEvents` your refering same array from props  i.e `Properties.events`.  And your mutating that array  using  `e.Markets =  propmarkets.filter....` and  `m.Selections = propselections.filter...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time `organizeEvents` function is called, it's just using the same array and mutating/changing it.

**Where is same array used ?**

```
const propevents = this.props.Properties.events; // (Properties.events) is an array that you are mutating
```

Here you just assigned the array to a variable `propevents`. It does not mean that the array is copied to the variable. The variable is just referring the same array.

**Where is the array mutated/changed ?**

1.

```
propevents.forEach(e => { 
   e.Markets = propmarkets.filter(m => m.Values.eventid === e.Id && m.Values.name.toUpperCase().includes(timeFilter));
```

Here you are looping through the `propevents` array and for every element in that array your mutating/changing the property `Markets` (which is an array).

2.

```
e.Markets.forEach(m => {
        m.Selections = propselections.filter(s => s.Values.marketid === m.Id);
    });
```

Here again your looping through the above mutated/changed `Markets` and for every element in the `Markets` array you are mutating/changing  the propery `Selections` (which is also an array).

**Solution**

Solution for this problem is to deep copy the array and mutate/change it.

**How**

1. You can make a utility function that deep copies array and object.

   ```
    // it's not the best but it does the job
      function deepCopy(o) {
         let output, v, key;
         output = Array.isArray(o) ? [] : {};
         for (key in o) {
           v = o[key];
           output[key] = typeof v === "object" && v !== null ? deepCopy(v) : v;
         }
         return output;
       };
   ```
2. Use it in the `organizeEvents` function

   ```
    const propevents = deepCopy(this.props.Properties.events);
   ```